# Output a good-looking matrix using renderTable()

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a matrix in my server. I would like to then output this matrix on the screen using renderTable(). (I create it in the server because its length (among others) depends on some other inputs in the ui).

As you will see with the code (or the attached picture) here below, the matrix that appears does not look good at all :it's a matrix with grey borders, rounded corners etc.

So the question: is there a way to control the appearance of the matrix ? For example, I may not want borders, I may want the rownames to be in Italics/bold etc...

```
shiny::runApp(
list(
ui = pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("TEST"),

sidebarPanel(
helpText('This matrix is pretty ugly:')
),

mainPanel(    
uiOutput('matrix')     
)
)
, 
server = function(input,output){
output$matrix <- renderTable({

matrix <- matrix(rep(1,6),nrow=3)

rownames(matrix) <- c('a','b','c')
matrix

})
}
)
)
```

[image]

Comment: You could use `xtable` to generate a LaTeX code and include it as Mathjax.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mathjax rendering:

```
library(xtable)

shiny::runApp(
  list(
    ui = pageWithSidebar(

      headerPanel("TEST"),

      sidebarPanel(
        helpText('Is this matrix cool ?')
      ),

      mainPanel(    
        uiOutput('matrix')     
      )
    )
    , 
    server = function(input,output){
      output$matrix <- renderUI({
        M <- matrix(rep(1,6),nrow=3)
        rownames(M) <- c('a','b','c')
        M <- print(xtable(M, align=rep("c", ncol(M)+1)), 
                          floating=FALSE, tabular.environment="array", comment=FALSE, print.results=FALSE)
        html <- paste0("$$", M, "$$")
        list(
          tags$script(src = 'https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/2.0-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML', type = 'text/javascript'),
          HTML(html)
        )
      })
    }
  )
)
```

[image]

## Update July 2015

Something has changed and the MathJax rendering does not work anymore. Maybe this is the link to the MathJax library, I don't know. Anyway, there's a new function in Shiny, `withMathJax`, which does the job. Replace the `server` function by the following one:

```
server = function(input,output){
    output$matrix <- renderUI({
        M <- matrix(rep(1,6),nrow=3)
        rownames(M) <- c('a','b','c')
        M <- print(xtable(M, align=rep("c", ncol(M)+1)), 
                   floating=FALSE, tabular.environment="array", comment=FALSE, print.results=FALSE)
        html <- paste0("$$", M, "$$")
        list(
            withMathJax(HTML(html))
        )
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephane ! Yes this one is really cool ! I am going to have a close look at MathJax

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent: When I run the code that you have written above, I get the following result: $$\begin{array}{ccc} \hline & 1 & 2 \\ \hline a & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ b & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ c & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ \hline \end{array} $$. Would you know why it doesnt print a table in my case? Thanks!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent the result is really beautiful. I was wondering if it could work with a `summary` table.

Comment: @Worice I believe there are some R packages providings functions that generate a LaTeX code rendering some summary tables (not all summary tables, this is case-specific). If the LaTeX code doesn't require some LaTeX packages, that could work with MathJax too.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent it seems they are constantly messing around with the older libraries. It seems to me that your July 2015 update is no longer valid again. :( I've just tried to run the code and got the same erroneous result that user3641630 mentioned earlier: $$\begin{array}{ccc} \hline & 1 & 2 \\ \hline a & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ b & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ c & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ \hline \end{array} $$

Comment: @lazarea I've just tried and it perfectly works. Do you open the app in the RStudio browser ? If yes, that could be the cause of the problem. Open it in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 7):

You can start fiddling with CSS, but for quick work the googleVis package is nice. Additional options to add decorations can be found in the documentation.

```
shiny::runApp(
  list(
    ui = pageWithSidebar(

      headerPanel("TEST"),

      sidebarPanel(
        helpText('This matrix is quite nice:')
      ),

      mainPanel(    
        uiOutput('matrix')     
      )
    )
    , 
    server = function(input,output){
      library(googleVis)
      output$matrix <- renderGvis({
        df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(9),nrow=3))      
        rownames(df) <- c('a','b','c')
        gvisTable(df);

      })
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Many thanks Dieter ! However, for some reason the row names (a,b,c) do not appear with this code. Any idea why ?

Comment: Could be that there is an option in the docs, I have not checked. But if that does not work, simply add the rownames as a separate first column to the data.frame.

Comment: thank you. Actually this does not work because the first column needs to get a heading too when one inserts it in the data frame. I am going to have a look at the docs (although at first sight, there is nothing regarding row names since this is a function for a table), and may ask this questions specifically on SO if I find no answer

Answer (score 0):

For rownames in googleVis package use:

```
 shiny::runApp(
  list(
ui = pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("TEST"),

  sidebarPanel(
    helpText('This matrix is quite nice:')
  ),

  mainPanel(    
    uiOutput('matrix')     
  )
)  
, 
server = function(input,output){
  library(googleVis)
  output$matrix <- renderGvis({
    df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(9),nrow=3))      
    df <- cbind(' ' = c('a','b','c'),df) 
    gvisTable(df);

  })
}
  )
)
```