# Centering, enlarging an xtable in RStudio Presentation

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have opened a Presentation file in RStudio and I am using stable package in the following code chunk:

````
```{r, results="asis",echo=FALSE}
library(xtable)
x <- matrix(c(28,11,50,3),nrow=2)
colnames(x) <- c("No Pet","Pet")
rownames(x) <- c("Alive","Dead")
print(xtable(x),type="html")
```
````

It produces the following slide:

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way (using the RStudio presentation---is it Shiny?) to center the table and make the fonts a little bigger.

Also, any way to get rid of the decimal points?

Finally, and this might not be possible with RStudio Presentation, is it possible to produce an image similar to this with xtable?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: David, there are a few options suggested here:

[Good looking matrix in Shiny][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251956/r-shiny-how-to-output-a-good-looking-matrix-using-rendertable