# Shiny: renderPlot() not appearing with withMathJax() upon app initialization?

Tags: r, shiny

I've been making a Shiny app that creates both plots and tables that depend on some slider-based settings. Everything works ok, except that when the app is run, the plot doesn't appear until you move one of the sliders. This is the case on multiple browsers and computers.

Here is an example:

```
#ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("mtcars example"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("mVal",
                  "Goal HP:",
                  min = 50,
                  max = 350,
                  value = 100)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot",width='1000px',height='600px'),
      uiOutput("view")
    )
  )
))

#server.R
library(ggplot2)
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    MTtemp <- mtcars
    MTtemp$distToTarget <- (MTtemp$hp - input$mVal)^2

    p1<-ggplot(MTtemp,aes(x=hp,y=mpg,col=log(distToTarget)))+geom_point()+scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c('red','lightblue'))
    print(p1)

  })

  output$view <- renderUI({
    MTtemp <- mtcars
    MTtemp$distToTarget <- (MTtemp$hp - input$mVal)^2

    tM<-head(MTtemp[order(MTtemp$distToTarget),],n=10)

    M <- print(xtable(tM), floating=FALSE, tabular.environment="array", comment=FALSE, print.results=FALSE)
    html <- paste0("$$", M, "$$")
    list(
      withMathJax(HTML(html))
    )
  })      
})
```

However, if rather than using renderUI() and mathjax/html I just go with a renderTable() the plot appears straight away as I would expect. I.e., replacing the output$view above with:

```
  output$view <- renderTable({
    MTtemp <- mtcars
    MTtemp$distToTarget <- (MTtemp$hp - input$mVal)^2
    head(MTtemp[order(MTtemp$distToTarget),],n=10)
  })
```

If all else fails this is a workable solution, but I'd prefer to go with the prettier renderUI/mathjax table. So, I was hoping that someone could provide insight into the interaction between these elements that is causing the plot not to appear initially, or whatever other error I'm making to produce these behaviours.

Edit: It appears to be the mathjax that causes the issue. Ideally I'd like some way to keep the mathjax while seeing the plot appear.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `html` object worked for me, and it seems to be the same output:

```
  output$view <- renderUI({
    MTtemp <- mtcars
    MTtemp$distToTarget <- (MTtemp$hp - input$mVal)^2

    tM<-head(MTtemp[order(MTtemp$distToTarget),],n=10)

    M <- print(xtable(tM), floating=FALSE, tabular.environment="array", comment=FALSE, print.results=FALSE)
    html <- paste0("$$", M, "$$")
#     list(
#       withMathJax(HTML(html))
#     )
    return(html)
  })
```

**EXAMPLE with renderTable**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    MTtemp <- mtcars
    MTtemp$distToTarget <- (MTtemp$hp - input$mVal)^2

    p1<-ggplot(MTtemp,aes(x=hp,y=mpg,col=log(distToTarget)))+geom_point()+scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c('red','lightblue'))
    print(p1)

  })

  output$view <- renderTable({
    MTtemp <- mtcars
    MTtemp$distToTarget <- (MTtemp$hp - input$mVal)^2

    tM<-head(MTtemp[order(MTtemp$distToTarget),],n=10)

    return(tM)

  }) 

})


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("mtcars example"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("mVal",
                  "Goal HP:",
                  min = 50,
                  max = 350,
                  value = 100)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot",width='1000px',height='600px'),
      tableOutput("view")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: So with that, the plot appears but the table ends up just as LaTeX code rather than a table. Presumably this indicates the problem is being caused by the mathjax. At least it gives me something else to think about...

Comment: it appears in the same way using that lines of code or not, for me. If you want a table, here is some [nice example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html)

Comment: See my edit with `renderTable` example. You can also change it for `renderDataTable` as in the previous link

Comment: I've gone with the renderTable temporarily as a backup option. Ideally I'd like to get the mathjax version working without the weird plot blocking.

Comment: Try asking @Stephane Laurent in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251956/output-a-good-looking-matrix-using-rendertable)