# Shiny renderTable add.to.row

Tags: r, shiny, xtable

I have a dataframe that could look like this

```
> df
Product    noPat     Val  Tot TotVal
Product A  -318 -108.12 1356 461.04
Product C   403  544.05  462  623.7
Product D   -32  -39.68  529 655.96
Product B   N/A     N/A  N/A    N/A
```

I would like to add two multicolumns using the add.to.row argmument in the xtable function.

```
print(xtable(df, digits=2, caption=strCaption, label="Test_table"), 
      size="footnotesize", #Change size; useful for bigger tables
      include.rownames=FALSE, #Don't print rownames
      caption.placement="top", 
      hline.after=NULL, #We don't need hline; we use booktabs
      add.to.row = list(pos = list(-1, 
                                   nrow(df)),
                        command = c(paste("\\hline \n",
                                          "& \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Growth} & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Total} \\\\ \n",
                                          "\\hline \n"),
                                    "\\hline \n")
      )
)
```

Which generates the desired latex output:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{test} 
\label{Test_table}
\begingroup\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
  \hline 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Growth} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Total} \\ 
 \hline 
Product & noPat & Val & Tot & TotVal \\ 
 Product A & -318 & -108.12 & 1356 & 461.04 \\ 
  Product C & 403 & 544.05 & 462 & 623.7 \\ 
  Product D & -32 & -39.68 & 529 & 655.96 \\ 
  Product B & N/A & N/A & N/A & N/A \\ 
   \hline 
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{table}
```

Which is the format I want. I would like Shiny to output this, but Shiny just adds the add.to.row argument as text output just above the table.

My implementation in Shiny:

Server.R

```
output$tabletest <- renderTable({
        rows <<- nrow(df)
        xtable(df, digits=2)

      },

      caption = "Sample Data",
      caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "bottom"), 
      caption.width = getOption("xtable.caption.width", NULL),
      include.rownames=getOption("xtable.include.rownames", FALSE), #Don't print rownames
      add.to.row = getOption("xtable.add.to.row",list(pos = list(-1, 
                                   rows),
                        command = c(paste("\\hline \n",
                                          "& \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Growth} & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Total} \\\\ \n",
                                          "\\hline \n"),
                                    "\\hline \n")))
      )
```

UI.R

```
tableOutput("tabletest")
```

**Using MathJax**

As suggested by NicE I tried to use MathJax in the following way

Server.R

```
output$tabletest<- renderUI({
        result <- withMathJax(HTML(
        "\\begin{table}[ht]
        \\centering
        \\caption{test}
        \\label{Test_table}
        \\begin{tabular}{lllll}
        \\hline
        & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Growth} & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Total} \\\\
        \\hline
        Product & noPat & Val & Tot & TotVal \\\\
        Product A & -318 & -108.12 & 1356 & 461.04 \\\\
        Product C & 403 & 544.05 & 462 & 623.7 \\\\
        Product D & -32 & -39.68 & 529 & 655.96 \\\\
        Product B & x & x & x & x \\\\
        \\hline
        \\end{tabular}
        \\end{table}"
        ))
 })
```

UI.R

```
              withMathJax(),
              uiOutput("KeyIndicatorsPatients")
```

But this results in

[image: MathJax output]

Comment: `renderTable` will use `type="html"` to print the `xtable`, but your `add.to.row` is Latex so they are not printed, you could use `withMathJax` to display the table, [here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251956/output-a-good-looking-matrix-using-rendertable)

Comment: @NicE thank you for your comment. I've tried implementing it, but it cannot render. Please have a look at my edit, if you have time.

Comment: you need to add the following arguments: `floating=FALSE, tabular.environment="array", comment=FALSE, print.results=FALSE` and also add the `$$` at the beginning and end of the code (it's done using paste in the link I posted). It turns out MathJax doesn't support `\multicolumn` so I guess the only options is to transform your extra row to html. I posted an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`renderTable` will use `type="html"` to print the xtable, but your `add.to.row` is Latex so they are not printed.

You could try transforming your code to `HTML`, for example:

```
output$tabletest <- renderTable({
    xtable(df,digits=2)
  },
  size="footnotesize", #Change size; useful for bigger tables
  include.rownames=FALSE, #Don't print rownames
  caption.placement="top",
  include.colnames=FALSE,
  add.to.row = list(pos = list(0),
                    command = "<tr><th></th><th colspan='2'>Growth</td><th colspan='2'>Total</th></tr>
<tr> <th> Product </th> <th> noPat </th> <th> Val </th> <th> Tot </th> <th> TotVal </th>  </tr>"
  ))
```

I added `include.colnames=FALSE` to your arguments and added them manually in the `add.to.row` to put them under your other header.

The result looks like this:

[image: table example]

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it out tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Works just as desired. Thank you!