# How to merge Column headers in dataframe in r

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I have a data-frame in R that looks like this.

```
Housing = c("Average Housing Year Built",
        "Owner Occupied",
        "Occupied Units",
        "Rent as a Percent of MFI",
        "All Residents",
        "Hispanic/Latino",
        "White",
        "Black",
        "Asian")

Values = c(1920, 5065886, 7255261, 99444.94, "20.54%", "27.7%", "18.67%",
           "36.64%", "42.42%")

Housing = data.frame(Housing, Values)
```

I'm trying to merge the column headers - `Housing$Housing` & `Housing$Values` into a Single cell called `Housing_characteristics` and the rest of the data frame must be the same. Exactly like an Excel spreadsheet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7AjF.jpg

I want the output to look something like this -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHd0C.jpg

I have a bunch of these data-frames that I'm displaying in an RShiny application and need to format the headers for a clean look.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample output that you want ?

Comment: the output that you want is not clear.  What do you mean by merging column headers? You can just create a new column named "Housing characteristics"

Comment: I've edited my post to include the output I'm trying to achieve. I could create a new column and merge all the contents, but I was hoping to merge just the column headers so that the demarcation between the values are clear. I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't think this is possible in R, since a common header would imply that it is one single column while they are not. If you want to instead output this as a nice readable table without storing it as a `data.frame`, then there are some options with latex tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the closest thing you can get:

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(Housing, summary = FALSE, type = "text",
          rownames = FALSE, align = TRUE, title = "Housing Characteristics")
```

**Text Table:**

```
Housing Characteristics
===================================
         Housing            Values 
-----------------------------------
Average Housing Year Built   1920  
      Owner Occupied       5065886 
      Occupied Units       7255261 
 Rent as a Percent of MFI  99444.94
      All Residents         20.54% 
     Hispanic/Latino        27.7%  
          White             18.67% 
          Black             36.64% 
          Asian             42.42% 
-----------------------------------
```

Note that this is *not* a `data.frame`. This is a table in text form outputted into your console, so you cannot manipulate it like a `data.frame`.

If you are fine with latex tables in your shiny app, you can also use the `type = latex` option, which is the default:

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(Housing, summary = FALSE, header = FALSE,
          title = "Housing Characteristics")
```

Latex Code:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Housing Characteristics} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} cc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Housing & Values \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Average Housing Year Built & 1920 \\ 
Owner Occupied & 5065886 \\ 
Occupied Units & 7255261 \\ 
Rent as a Percent of MFI & 99444.94 \\ 
All Residents & 20.54\% \\ 
Hispanic/Latino & 27.7\% \\ 
White & 18.67\% \\ 
Black & 36.64\% \\ 
Asian & 42.42\% \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

[image]

This would look quite nice on a shiny app!

Comment: Thanks a lot useR! This looks really cool, I should explore these kind of tables more! Quick question though, how would I render this through my app? I tried to insert your code into one of my output objects on the server side and was only getting the Latex code. Not getting the output table in your second image. I'm currently using a mix of renderTables and renderDataTables that are tab-setted to show different attributes.

Comment: @AshwinRamesh There's a function in `shiny` called `withMathJax` which would render latex. You may want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251956/output-a-good-looking-matrix-using-rendertable. If you are still having issues, it might be better to ask a new question specifically about rendering latex tables in shiny

Answer (score 2):

Modify the displayed output and not the `data.frame`.  The following will draw an interactive table with title and still allow columns to be sorted:

```
library(DT)

sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      th(colspan = 2, 'Housing Characteristics')
    ),
    tr(
      th('Description'),
      th('Values')
    )
  )
))

datatable(Housing, container = sketch, rownames = FALSE)
```

[image]

example derived from section 2.5 of http://rstudio.github.io/DT/