# Render reactive stargazer tables in LaTeX format

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to display `{stargazer}` tables with the LaTeX format in a Shiny app, since some options only concern LaTeX (for example `table.placement`). I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22337591/11598948) that uses `withMathJax` but the following example does not work for me, I just have some LaTeX code in a "box":

```
library(shiny)
library(stargazer)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  regression <- lm(mpg ~ drat + hp + disp, data =  mtcars)

  table_output <- reactive({
      stargazer(regression)
  })

  output$test <- renderUI({
    withMathJax(HTML(table_output()))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to render reactive stargazer table in LaTeX format?

Comment: MathJax does not support `\multicolumn`. A possibility is to convert the LaTeX code to a png image with the help of the `texPreview` package, and then include this png image in the app.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I am having some trouble with the  `texPreview` package (actually I can't even run [these examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texPreview/vignettes/classes.html) properly), could you show how to use it in my example?

Comment: @ bretauv, what kind of problem do you encounter? Do you get an error message? Otherwise, if `texPreview` does not work, we can use GhostScript to convert the compiled pdf to a png image. Do you have GhostScript?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I have tried to do `tex_preview(tex_lines = stargazer(regression))` (`regression` is defined in the example in my post) with the same `tex_opts` as [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texPreview/vignettes/classes.html). I have the error `! LaTeX Error: Environment table undefined.` which apparently appears in LaTeX when no `\documentclass` or `\begin{document}` is specified. I have GhostScript

Comment: Could you try `tex_preview(obj = paste0(stargazer(regression), collapse="\n"))`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent It works locally but when I put this into a `renderImage`, I have an error: `Error in $: object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable`

Comment: Wait, I'm looking for a way to embed the pdf. In this way we will be able to copy the text in the table.

Comment: Do you have the `pdfinfo` program installed on your computer?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes I have

Comment: Obligatory note that you shouldn’t use ‘stargazer’, because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘texreg’ instead, or literally *anything* else.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, I will keep this in mind and check the `texreg` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathJax does not support the LaTeX code generated by `stargazer`.

Here is a solution. It compiles the LaTeX code with the help of `tools::texi2pdf` and it uses the JavaScript library `PDFobject` to embed the PDF. Moreover, it uses the `pdfinfo` program to get appropriate dimensions (width and height) for the PDF viewer.

```
library(shiny)
library(stargazer)

js <- function(width, height){
  sprintf('
var options = {
  width: "%dpx",
  height: "%dpx",
  pdfOpenParams: { 
    view: "Fit", 
    scrollbar: "0", 
    toolbar: "0", 
    statusbar: "0", 
    messages: "0",
    navpanes: "0"
  }
};
PDFObject.embed("mypdf.pdf", "#pdf", options);
', width, height)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfobject/2.1.1/pdfobject.min.js")
  ),
  uiOutput("pdfcontainer")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output[["pdfcontainer"]] <- renderUI({
    tmpDir <- tempdir()
    texfile <- file.path(tmpDir, "table.tex")
    pdffile <- file.path(tmpDir, "table.pdf")
    infofile <- file.path(tmpDir, "table.txt")
    regression <- lm(mpg ~ drat + hp + disp, data =  mtcars)
    LaTeX <- stargazer(regression, float = FALSE)
    writeLines(
      c(
        "\\documentclass[12pt, border={20pt 20pt 20pt 20pt}]{standalone}",
        "\\begin{document}",
        LaTeX,
        "\\end{document}"
      ),
      texfile
    )
    file.remove("www/mypdf.pdf")
    owd <- setwd(tmpDir)
    tools::texi2pdf(texfile, clean = TRUE)
    setwd(owd)
    file.copy(pdffile, "www/mypdf.pdf", overwrite = TRUE)
    command <- sprintf("pdfinfo -box www/mypdf.pdf > %s", infofile)
    system(command)
    info <- readLines(infofile)
    pageSize <- info[grep("Page size:", info)]
    dimensions <- as.numeric(
      unlist(
        regmatches(pageSize, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*", pageSize))
      )
    )
    width <- max(300, floor(dimensions[1]))
    height <- floor(width*dimensions[2]/dimensions[1])
    tagList(
      tags$div(id = "pdf"),
      tags$script(HTML(js(width, height)))
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I have some issues, like `Warning in file.remove("www/mypdf.pdf") :
  impossible to remove the file 'www/mypdf.pdf', because of 'No file or folder of this type'` and `Warning in file.create(to[okay]) :
  impossible to create the file 'www/mypdf.pdf', because of 'No file or folder or this type"` (translation of the error message so maybe it is not 100% accurate). Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: @bretauv Ah perhaps you just have to create the **www** subfolder.

Comment: Right, it was necessary. Note that the first time this app runs, it throws an error with `file.remove()` since no file is created yet. However, for unknown reason (no error message), the shiny app only displays "Impossible to load the plug-in" and I have no idea why

Comment: @bretauv Hmmm what is the browser you use? For me this works fine with Chrome.

Comment: I was running it in an RStudio window. It works fine for firefox (it may necessary to disable some extensions though). Isn't it possible to run it in an RStudio window?